# Is there any Package for adding Arrows to lines in leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, line, interactive

I am working on an interactive map in Leaflet thorough R studio, I want to show the direction of the roads with Arrows. I would be grateful if anyone helps me which package I should use for this

Comment: leaflet.minicharts seems to provide this feature, see [addFlows](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet.minicharts/versions/0.6.2/topics/addFlows).

Comment: This is more a question for a redit group

Answer (score 1):

the [`leaflet.extras2` package](https://github.com/trafficonese/leaflet.extras2) now contains the [`Arrowheads`-plugin](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-arrowheads) that provides this functionality.